# Creating mobile application with sencha touch 2 with eclipse ide

Tags: eclipse, sencha-touch-2

I am new to sencha touch. I want to  create a mobile application in eclipse ide.
Can anyone tell me how to do that? I got many links for creating web app but none for mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I recommend is that you get started with sencha command, this will help you when building out the app for native packaging, not to mention creating an initial app for you with the basic essentials: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/command

Android Packaging: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/native_android
iOS Packaging: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/native_packaging

This next one talks about phonegap and working with eclipse... which since sencha command is available, 3rd party sdk's like phonegap would be the only rrason to compile in eclipse, otherwise sencha command can handle it.... http://andidog.de/blog/2012/06/packaging-a-sencha-touch-2-application-with-phonegap-for-android/